# retrieve href attributes from url with php

Tags: php, url, dom, href

i want to retrieve the href attributes within all the anchor tags on the homepage url provided by the `website1`, crawl the website by one level depth, and retrieve the href attributes within all the anchor tags found on the crawled page, but it doesn't show anything. the function i used is `findAndCompare`.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
website: <input type="text" name="website1"><br>
website: <input type="text" name="website2"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html> 

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    // form has been submitted
    $form_data = $_POST['website1'];
    findAndCompare($form_data);

  }
  else
  {}

function findAndCompare($url){

// Create a DOM parser object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($url);

// Iterate over all the <a> tags
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        // Show the <a href>
        echo $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo "<br />";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: as a recommendation: jquery/javascript would be much better suited for this task

Comment: How do you want to do this using javascript with an external URL @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs?

Comment: @Syscall well, it depends if the crawl target is samedomain - or if it has correct Headers set up - but you could echo and crawl that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`loadHTML()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) requires HTML source, not an URL. You could load the source with [`loadHTMLFile()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) instead:

```
function findAndCompare($url){

    // Create a DOM parser object
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    // load HTML from URL
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);

    // Iterate over all the <a> tags
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        // Show the <a href>
        echo $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```